# Custom Sort Order by Ids as array in elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch, custom-sort

The scenario is like this we send the products id's in array as [101,102,103,.....so on  ]
but in response  we aren't getting the results in the same order is there any way to get the records in the same order as we send in the elastic search query

Comment: As per doc "When you get a document back from Elasticsearch, any arrays will be in the same order as when you indexed the document. The _source field that you get back contains exactly the same JSON document that you indexed". Can you elaborate your issue more?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found a solution let me share it with you , although thanks a lot for your precious time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "my_videos": {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "createdAt": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "duration": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "lastUpdatedByUserId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "updatedAt": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "url": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



GET my_videos/doc/_search
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                        "match": {
                            "id.keyword": "01cm7kr0px0tmyzkmsjb55xd3a"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "id.keyword": "01cktwwyfnyt9d2nqj9ycwxcme"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "id.keyword": "01chyvzv678r1h0y0rx4e4bv8t"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1
            }
        },
        "sort": [{
            "_script": {
                "type": "number",
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "inline": "if(params.scores.containsKey(doc['id.keyword'].value)) { return params.scores[doc['id.keyword'].value];} return 100000;",
                    "params": {
                        "scores": {
                            "01cm7kr0px0tmyzkmsjb55xd3a": 0,
                            "01cktwwyfnyt9d2nqj9ycwxcme": 1,
                            "01chyvzv678r1h0y0rx4e4bv8t": 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }],
        "from": 0,
        "size": 10
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).